# QuestDB Using Single CPU Core for Query

Tags: questdb

I'm benchmarking QuestDB for query performance, for that I selected a 181 Million row CSV dataset and bulk loaded the data into QuestDB.

While querying the loaded dataset I saw a strange behavior that it's only using a single CPU core (used `top`). I threw a complex SQL query still it's only using a single CPU core.

I've set the `shared.worker.count` to `8`.

Any suggestions on how to make the Engine use more than 1 CPU core for Querying the data.

Comment: Hi Saif. Parallel query filter execution should be included into the next QuestDB release. For now, only certain types of aggregate queries may utilize multiple cores.

The PR to follow the progress is this one: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/pull/1732

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll look forward to those updates in the future.